# Change flags to kubernetes api-server running inside Docker for Mac

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac

I am running kubernetes inside 'Docker Desktop' on Mac OS High Sierra.

[image]

Is it possible to change the flags given to the kubernetes api-server with this setup?

I can see that the api-server is running.

[image]

I am able to exec into the api-server container. When I kill the api-server so I could run it with my desired flags, the container is immediately killed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this to find the name of kube-apiserver pod name:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep apiserver
```

Grab the name of the pod and edit its configuration:

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit pod APISERVER_POD_NAME
```

When you do that, the editor will open and you can change apiserver command line flags from there.
After editing you should save and close the editor, your changes will be applied.

Comment: Great answer @Vasily Angapov. I am only seeing 1 deployment in kube-system namespace though. " kubectl -n kube-system get deployment" is returning just the kube-dns. Looks like the kubernetes cluster in the 'Docker for mac' isn't a typical setup?

Comment: Under this directory: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/`  should be placed `kube-apiserver.yaml` 
Looking for kube-apiserver please try and use  `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` instead of deployment.

Comment: Note - for kubeadm based system, you may not get the deployment. Alternatively, you can edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml an delete the kube-apiserver pod to restart it

Answer (score 2):

I there is no a deployment for `kube-apiserver` since those pods are static so they are created and managed by `kubelet`.

The way to change `kube-api`'s parameters is like @hanx mentioned:

1. ssh into the master node (not a container);
2. update the file under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/`;
   As soon as you save the file, the changes will take effect.

Comment: Do you know how to ssh into the kube-apiserver in mac docker-desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to kill the api-server to modify desired flags.
api-server is a pod as @alex mentioned.

just modify api-server manifest file and save it for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).